# Custom http header

Tags: http-headers, meteor

I'm looking at the meteor example apps. I've just been playing around really. How would I be able to add a custom http header to a page (say the leaderboard sample)?

Edit: I'm not using Apache or Nginx im using meteor (meteor.com) it has its own built in server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do but if you want to add headers all the time try...

NGINX: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-send-custom-http-headers/

APACHE: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html

Comment: Im using meteor not really nginx or apache

Comment: I see so you deploy on meteor.com? This may not be available to do yet until meteor allows you to deploy on your own server. I've been using meteor a lot lately and it is definitely not ready for more complex apps.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP method accepts a dictionary object for headers ex:

```
        HTTP.call(method,route,{
          headers:{
              "Content-Type":"application/json"
          }
        })
```